# Detect recursion when overridding trait methods

Tags: php, laravel, traits

Two libraries provide each inside a trait, a method to override a default base class method.

```
// This is a Framework base class
class Model { 
  function getAttribute($key) {
    return "Model->$key";
  }
}

// This is a trait from library A which provides extra stuff
trait HasUuid {
  function getAttribute($key) {
    if ($key==='uuid') return "HasUuid->$key";

    return parent::getAttribute($key);
  }
}

// This is a trait from library B which provides extra stuff
trait HasQuantity {
  function getAttribute($key) {
    if ($key==='quantity') return "HasQuantity->$key";

    return parent::getAttribute($key);
  }
}
```

Now, I have a class in my application which inherits from `Model` and needs to use both traits.

PHP allows to alias the trait functions in order to resolve naming conflicts between libraries. So here is what I end up with:

```
class Product extends Model {
  use HasUuid { getAttribute as getHasUuidAttribute; }
  use HasQuantity { getAttribute as getHasQuantityAttribute; }

  function getAttribute($key) {
    // Framework default value to use as fallback
    $parentValue = parent::getAttribute($key);

    $overrides = ['getHasUuidAttribute', 'getHasQuantityAttribute',];

    foreach ($overrides as $override)
    {
      $overriddenValue = $this->$override($key);

      // A trait has some better value than the fallback
      if ($overriddenValue !== $parentValue) return $overriddenValue;
    }

    // Nothing better, use fallback from framework
    return $parentValue;
  }
}
```

We end up with a recursion issue: when calling the overridden trait methods, their refer to the `parent::getAttribute` method which triggers another call to `Product::getAttribute` which recurses infinitly.

How can we solve this recursion issue, by keeping access to both trait features?

Of course, as the traits each come from a library, I cannot change their code.

Comment: Have you tried detecting recursion? .... (I'm sorry, this is a terrible pun and I'm probably going to hell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of making these private using a `private` keyword.

```
class Product extends Model {
  use HasUuid { getAttribute as private getHasUuidAttribute; }
  use HasQuantity { getAttribute as private getHasQuantityAttribute; }

  function getAttribute($key) {
    // Framework default value to use as fallback
    $parentValue = parent::getAttribute($key);

    $overrides = ['getHasUuidAttribute', 'getHasQuantityAttribute',];

    foreach ($overrides as $override)
    {
      $overriddenValue = $this->$override($key);

      // A trait has some better value than the fallback
      if ($overriddenValue !== $parentValue) return $overriddenValue;
    }

    // Nothing better, use fallback from framework
    return $parentValue;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting. It works but I would love to understand how that works in details. Thank you already for the solution. Would be great to get more details.